# Create multiple records from one form (MS Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I'm creating a database that will be used to keep track of maintenance performed on equipment in a nursing home. I'm using MS Access 2010, and I'd say my skills are somewhere between novice and intermediate, almost entirely self-taught for this project.

The database structure is as follows:

```
tblAssetTypes: 
  TypeID (PK), 
  MaintenanceSchedule, 
  EquipmentType, 
  EquipmentSubgroup, 
  MaintenanceTime, 
  TasksRequired

tblUniqueAssets: 
  UniqueID (PK), 
  StorageLocation, 
  TypeID (FK)

tblPrevMaintRecord: 
  ID (PK), 
  UniqueID (FK), 
  DatePerformed, 
  TimePerformed, 
  MaintenanceComments
```

I currently have a form that can be used to record when preventative maintenance is performed on an individual asset. The user enters the UniqueID for that asset, and details about the maintenance (date, time, comments), and then this information is saved to `tblPrevMaintRecord`. That works fine, but when I presented it to my supervisor he pointed out that in many instances, maintenance people would gather all equipment of a certain type and complete the preventative maintenance in one batch. Needing to enter that data in multiple times would be very tedious and so he asked if it would be possible to record the maintenance performed on multiple items at once. I've spent all day trying to research how to do this but can't seem to find anything that explains how this would be possible.

For each kind of asset, there is one TypeID. However, some values for EquipmentType, such as "Trolley" have subgroups recorded in EquipmentSubgroup (in the example of trolleys, "Medication", "Laundry", "Dressing", "Food", etc.). If there is no subgroup for an EquipmentType, such as "Bed", the EquipmentSubgroup is recorded as a dash "-".

I think ideally, the user should be able to selected any EquipmentType or EquipmentSubgroup category, be shown a list of assets in those categories and the corresponding UniqueIDs, and then select the UniqueIDs that they wish to act on. Then they complete the details of the maintenance (date, time, comments) and records are added for each UniqueID reflecting the maintenance performed on each item. I worry this might be too complicated, and I'm open to compromise solutions.

This is my first time posting here after being a long-term reader, so I hope I've given all the information and detail required for people to be able to help! This database has not been rolled out yet either, so if anyone has other suggestions that they think might be helpful I'm happy to hear them!

Comment: This seems a bit broad. What have you tried, and what's the step you're struggling with? Are you having trouble populating a combo box with a list of types and subgroups? Or populating a listbox with the unique IDs after making a selection? If you have some VBA knowledge, these tasks should be easily achievable, without it not so much.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I've managed to make it work as I wanted! I needed to break down some of the components into smaller steps and I figured out how to get through each step. I originally deleted this question cause I don't think leaving it up helps much, but figured I should respond to not be rude. Let me know if deleting it is the preferred approach.